# Optimal way to count number of elements that have successors

Tags: python, arrays, list

Given a list of n (un-ordered and possibly repeated) elements, I want to count the number of elements, i, such that their successor, i+1, is also in the list.

This is a problem a friend gave me that I can't find an optimal solution for large n (100,000) with element values up to 1,000,000,000. Below is my current approach with a randomly generated list, that take a long time to work.

```
import random
temp = random.sample(range(1000000000),random.randint(2,100000))
total_sum = 0
for i in range(len(temp)):
    if (temp[i]+1) in temp:
        total_sum+=1
print(total_sum)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
import random
random.seed(42)

temp = random.sample(range(1000000000), random.randint(2, 100000))

s = set(temp)
total_sum = sum(e + 1 in s for e in temp)
print(total_sum)
```

**Output**

```
7
```

The lookup time in a set is *O(1)* versus a list that is *O(n)*. The approach using a set is *O(n)*, your current implementation is *O(n^2)*.